# is it possible to install poetry groups with pip?

Tags: pip, python-packaging, python-poetry

As recomended by poetry, I'm using groups for dev specific dependencies ("test", "docs", and "dev").

I would to use them in automated tools such as github actions, readthedocs and nox which are more bounds to pip installation.

Is it possible to install specific groups from poetry as I do with setuptools based packages ?

```
pip install my_lib[dev]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it is not possible. The `[tool.poetry.group]` section of `pyproject.toml` is proprietary to *Poetry*, its content does not follow a standard specification. Technically speaking, nothing prevents any tool (including *pip*) to implement support for this *Poetry*-specific feature, but as far as I know no tool has implemented this support (besides *Poetry* of course).

*Poetry*'s own documentation chapter "[*Managing dependencies*](https://python-poetry.org/docs/managing-dependencies/#dependency-groups)" says the following on the matter:

> Dependency groups, other than the implicit `main` group, must only contain dependencies you need in your development process. Installing them is only possible by using Poetry.
>
> To declare a set of dependencies, which add additional functionality to the
> project during runtime, use [extras](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#extras) instead. Extras can be installed by the end user using `pip`.

Other tools have their own way of handling similar concepts of dependency groups. For example [*Hatch*](https://hatch.pypa.io/latest/config/environment/overview/#dependencies), and [*PDM*](https://pdm.fming.dev/latest/usage/dependency/#add-development-only-dependencies).

You might be interested in reading, following, and weighing in on these discussions regarding the standardization of such dependency groups so that they can be used in interoperable manner by various tools (including *pip* potentially):

- [PEP 735: Dependency Groups in `pyproject.toml`](https://discuss.python.org/t/-/39233) (latest proposed standard)
- [*Adding a non-metadata installer-only `dev-dependencies` table to pyproject.toml*](https://discuss.python.org/t/adding-a-non-metadata-installer-only-dev-dependencies-table-to-pyproject-toml/20106) (historical discussion)
- [*Development Dependencies In pyproject.toml*](https://discuss.python.org/t/development-dependencies-in-pyproject-toml/26149) (historical discussion)

Answer (score 1):

In a local environment and also CI context, it's possible to run the following for a group `[tool.poetry.group.docs.dependencies]`

```
poetry export -f requirements.txt --without-hashes --only docs -o only-docs.txt
pip install -r only-docs.txt
```

This however does not work in a deployed version of the package on an pypi index. As others have stated, Poetry groups are not a standard.
Creating a standardized and pip-recognizable optional group requires the usage of [Poetry extras](https://python-poetry.org/docs/master/pyproject#extras).